# AWK - Printing a specific pattern

Tags: regex, awk, pattern-matching

I have file that looks like this

```
gene_id_100100  sp|Q53IZ1|ASDP_PSESP    35.81   148 90  2   13  158 6   150 6e-27    109    158 531
gene_id_100600  sp|Q49W80|Y1834_STAS1   31.31   99  63  2   1   95  279 376 7e-07   50.1    113 402
gene_id_100     sp|A7TSV7|PAN1_VANPO    36.36   44  24  1   41  80  879 922 1.9 32.3    154 1492
gene_id_10100   sp|P37348|YECE_ECOLI    32.77   177 104 6   3   172 2   170 2e-13   71.2    248 272
gene_id_101100  sp|B0U4U5|SURE_XYLFM    29.11   79  41  3   70  148 143 206 0.14    35.8    175 262
gene_id_101600  sp|Q5AWD4|BGLM_EMENI    35.90   39  25  0   21  59  506 544 4.9 30.4    129 772
gene_id_102100  sp|P20374|COX1_APILI    38.89   36  22  0   3   38  353 388 0.54    32.0    92  521
gene_id_102600  sp|Q46127|SYW_CLOLO     79.12   91  19  0   1   91  1   91  5e-44    150    92  341
gene_id_103100  sp|Q9UJX6|ANC2_HUMAN    53.57   28  13  0   11  38  608 635 2.1 28.9    42  822
gene_id_103600  sp|C1DA02|SYL_LARHH     35.59   59  30  2   88  138 382 440 4.6 30.8    140 866
gene_id_104100  sp|B8DHP2|PROB_LISMH    25.88   85  50  2   37  110 27  109 0.81    32.3    127 276
gene_id_105100  sp|A1ALU1|RL3_PELPD     31.88   69  42  2   14  77  42  110 2.2 31.6    166 209
gene_id_105600  sp|P59696|T200_SALTY    64.00   125 45  0   5   129 3   127 9e-58    182    129 152
gene_id_10600   sp|G3XDA3|CTPH_PSEAE    28.38   74  48  1   4   77  364 432 0.56    31.6    81  568
gene_id_106100  sp|P94369|YXLA_BACSU    35.00   100 56  3   25  120 270 364 4e-08   53.9    120 457
gene_id_106600  sp|P34706|SDC3_CAEEL    60.00   20  8   0   18  37  1027    1046    2.3 32.7    191 2150
```

Now, I need to extract the gene ID, which is the one between || in the second column. In other words, I need an output that looks like this:

```
Q53IZ1  
Q49W80  
A7TSV7  
P37348  
B0U4U5  
Q5AWD4  
P20374  
Q46127  
Q9UJX6  
C1DA02  
B8DHP2  
A1ALU1  
P59696  
G3XDA3  
P94369
P34706
```

I have been trying to do it using the following command:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){ if($i==/[A-Z][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]/){print $i} } }'
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching is not really necessary. I'd suggest

```
awk -F\| '{print $2}' filename
```

This splits the line into `|`-delimited fields and prints the second of them.

Alternatively,

```
cut -d\| -f 2 filename
```

achieves the same.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly! And it seems so simple too, not like the paragraph of code I was trying to use haha. Thanks a lot for your help, I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes when the restriction is off. You are a life saver.

Comment: Although, if you have the time, could you tell me why the command I was using didn't work?

Comment: Hm, where to begin. Well, firstly, the stuff between the `|` was not a field as far as awk was concerned, because its default field separator is a sequence of whitespaces. `$2` of the first line is `sp|Q53IZ1|ASDP_PSESP` in your code. Secondly, you use the comparison operator `==` instead of the regex matching operator `~`, which does not make a lot of sense with regexes. I don't think what it does is defined; gawk appears to do numerical conversion (?). And if you had used `~`, then you'd have printed the field that contained the match, not the match itself.

Comment: So you would have had to extract the match. That would look something like this: `awk '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { pos = match($i, /[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{5}/); if(pos != 0) { print substr($i, pos, RLENGTH); } } } '`. Note that the regex matching is not confined to the second column this way; if there was, say, a `gene_id_A12345`, `A12345` would appear in the result list. I'm not sure I understand why you felt the need to iterate over all fields, to be honest, since you appeared to be only interested in `$2`.

Comment: I guess I still have a lot to learn, though this will be really helpful for me in the future. Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I could have seen some sense in `awk '{ p = match($2, /\|.*\|/); if(p != 0) { print substr($2, p + 1, RLENGTH - 2); } }'`, to spin the idea a bit.

Comment: The only explanation I can give you is that I am a complete noob :(

Comment: You will be astonished to learn that everyone who's good at anything was bad at it in the beginning. :P Just keep at it. And really, I don't think there's anyone who didn't have problems wrapping their head around regexes in the beginning.

Comment: @MPR6 get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.